# AWS Cognito for Xamarin

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to follow [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-android-sdk.html) guide for creating a new user, changing password, etc... using AWS Cognito and AWS user pools. I can't seem to find the proper Xamarin SDK for Android/iOS. Is there one that exists?

More specifically I'm having issues creating a Cognito User Pool object. In the sample I linked they have this:

```
CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(context, userPoolId, clientId, clientSecret);

// user pool can also be created with client app configuration:
CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool(context, userPoolId, clientId, clientSecret, clientConfiguration);
```

There doesn't seem to be a `CognitoUserPool` class. I can't find anything in the `AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity` library that is similar or has similar constructors or anything. Am I missing something or is this just not supported yet?

I also can't find anything similar to the `SignUpHandler` class from the `Register a new user` sample code shown here:

```
// create a handler for registration 
SignUpHandler handler = new SignUpHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(CognitoUser user, boolean signUpConfirmation) {
        // The sign up was successful, "user" is a CognitoUser object of the user who was signed up.

        // "signUpConfirmation" will indicate if user is already confirmed.
    }

    @override
    public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
        // Sign up failed, code check the exception for cause and perform remedial actions.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38739832/3204480) a similar question in another post.

The short answer, currently, Cognito User Pools client side SDK is not supported for Xamarin/Unity SDKs. The API shapes are avaialable to interact with the service directly but you will not find helper like `CognitoUserPool` and `CognitoUser` in any other SDK other than Android, iOS and JavaScript.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I hope they are planning on updating their Xamarin SDKs soon.

Comment: Is this still the case? It's now almost 4 months after you posted this.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon provides a C#/.NET SDK via NuGet, which will be the most up-to-date version and should provide the functionality that you require.

You can find this package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity/

You can also download the NuGet via the NuGet Console:

```
Install-Package AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity -Version 3.1.1.2
```

Finally, it can be added via NuGet Packages in Xamarin Studio by searching for:

```
AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes I saw that. But there seems to be a few things missing. I see no class similar to the `CognitoUserPool` class in the Android example I linked. Nor could I find any similar samples for the Xamarin AWS SDK. I'm not sure they have that in the Xamarin AWS SDK yet since it's still considered beta.

Comment: Hey! Let me do some testing and ask around the team here internally. I will get back to you :)

Comment: Hey! Spoke with the team here, and it appears the most updated version would be the following NuGet, furnished by Amazon: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity/ I will edit my answer to reflect this package

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I'm still having trouble figuring out how to create a `CognitoUserPool` object or something similar. I know Cognito User Pools is still very new so I am wondering if they even have that functionality implemented in the SDK. It looks like they don't. I'll edit my answer to reflect the specific problem I'm having with that SDK.

Comment: Hey, I will do some more digging :)

Comment: hello @clb, can please share what did you find?

Comment: I believe they dont have CognitoUserPool in latest SDK yet. It is very much upsetting that they are too slow on this. just 3 functions would be even sufficient. Signup, Signin, forgot password.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question / answer is old, but my search brought me here and hopefully I can help others.

You can now utilize user pools in the AWS .Net SDK by installing the AWSSDK.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication Nuget package.

Nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using AWS Cognito with Xamarin Forms:

https://github.com/curtisshipley/CognitoForms