# Amazon CognitoUserPool and other Objects do not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-cognito, portable-class-library

I am trying to get started with the Cognito User authentication and login services. I am using a Xamarin PCL on Visual Studio 2015. I have a User Pool already created and all the necessary SDK's installed (.Core, .CognitoIdentity, .CognitoIdentityProvider, etc.).

However, when following the Getting Started guide, none of the Objects that are used in the guide exist in any of the libraries! I have been dealing with this for 2 weeks now and I have given up.

All I have are CognitoIdentityProviderExceptions/Configs/Client/Request/etc. as well as the AWSCredentials Objects. But, none of the CognitoUser Objects or Handlers exist so I cannot get anything started. What am I missing? I have downloaded all the SDKs and even the Xamarin Components but nothing is there.

If anyone knows what I am missing please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been added via C# CognitoAuthentication Extension Library

Quote from aws blog:

> We are pleased to announce the Developer Preview of the
>   CognitoAuthentication extension library. This library simplifies the
>   authentication process of Amazon Cognito User Pools for .NET 4.5, .NET
>   Core, and Xamarin developers.

Code sample:

```C#
using System;
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Runtime;
using Amazon.S3;
using Amazon.S3.Model;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentity;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider;
using Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication;

public async void GetS3BucketsAsync()
{
    var provider = new AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(),
                                                            FallbackRegionFactory.GetRegionEndpoint());
    CognitoUserPool userPool = new CognitoUserPool("poolID", "clientID", provider);
    CognitoUser user = new CognitoUser("username", "clientID", userPool, provider);

    string password = "userPassword";

    AuthFlowResponse context = await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(new InitiateSrpAuthRequest()
    {
        Password = password
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = 
        user.GetCognitoAWSCredentials("identityPoolID", RegionEndpoint.<YourIdentityPoolRegion>);

    using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials))
    {
        ListBucketsResponse response = 
            await client.ListBucketsAsync(new ListBucketsRequest()).ConfigureAwait(false);

        foreach (S3Bucket bucket in response.Buckets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bucket.BucketName);
        }
    }
}
```

- [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/cognitoauthentication-extension-library-developer-preview/)
- [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication)

Answer (score 0):

The `CognitoUser` object or `Handlers` belong to the Cognito client side SDKs for Android, iOS and JavaScript only. Any other SDK is currently not supported for client side development and is only currently only powered with the low level shapes to interact directly with the APIs.

To know more about the platforms supported for client side development, you can read the sections for individual platforms [in the developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Are you saying that the Cognito SDK is not supported on Xamarin? They have a PCL project for it which makes me assume that it is. I am also having this problem on native Android as well which should be supported by Cognito SDK.

Comment: Yes. Cognito User Pools is not supported for Xamarin as of now. If you use the [Cognito Identity Provider SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/tree/master/aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider) in Android this should be available to you.

Comment: I am using the Identity Provider in Android and I am still having the same issue.